# phonegap smscomposer called from an externeal aspx website

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, plugins, cordova

i am making a mobile app with phonegap where the main page was made with MVC ASP.NET. When the ios-phonegap app starts,  we redirect it to the ASP.NET page. What we have to do is to call the SMSComposer phonegap plugin implemented in the ios phonegap app from the MVC ASPNET page.

Is this possible??, or i have to create all the html, js and css files in the www folder of the phonegap ios app and call it from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create all the html, js and css files in the www folder of the phonegap ios app and call it from there.
Even if it works in an external server, apple won't approve the app